# Is there any way to programmatically set Google group member settings?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-groups

As the topic says, is there any way to programmatically change Google's group member settings. Say for example the setting as to have emails sent to a group distributed to a particular member (one can be in a group without receiving mails sent to the group). There is a multitude of group member settings like this, but I haven't found a way to do it by API.

The first ideas would be the Admin Directory API or Groups Settings API, but neither supports any operations like these (the latter only has operations that affect the group as a whole).

Answer (score 0):

Within the Admin SDK, there's the Groups Settings API as you mentioned. Everything this API can do from an admin level is found [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/manage).

As far as I know, if it's not a setting available in this API, it won't be possible via API.